# ios audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying method not call sometime

Tags: ios, delegates, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I am making fun voice apps like TALKINGTOM.I have used avaudiorecoder to voice record continues when user talks. and play recording voice using avaudioplayer. i have also used timer to continues trigering user voice.it's working perfectlly.my problem is when avaudioplayer play complete then delegate method **audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying** some time not call.

I have used delegate method to retrigger timer and some other methods when it's call.I have also try to used coustom delegate method of avaudioplayer but it's not working.

I have initialised AVAudioplayer like this

```
  _player.delegate=self;

  [_player setVolume:1.0f];

  [_player play];
```

also declare avaudioplayer delegate in haderfile.

Here is my coustom delegate method protocoal decleration

@protocol MyAudioPlayerDelegate

-(void)myAudioPlayerFinishPlaying;

and then implement deleage method

```
[_player setDelegate:_MyAudioPlayerDelegate];

[_MyAudioPlayerDelegate performSelector:@selector(myAudioPlayerFinishPlaying)];

if ([_MyAudioPlayerDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myAudioPlayerFinishPlaying)]) {

    [_MyAudioPlayerDelegate myAudioPlayerFinishPlaying];
}
```

so please give some strong answer to how can solve audioplayerdidfinished method call every time.
Specially thanks in advance for give me your suggestion